# Vespa Sprint 50cc (2023), stalls if I give it only a little bit of gas after cold start - normal or not?

Tags: moped, vespa

Good evening.
Sorry if this is a dumb question, as this is my first IC moped - before I've only ridden electric ones.

I've discovered that if I start the engine on my brand new Vespa Sprint, and only give a little bit of gas (like I'd normally do with electric ones, otherwise I'd shoot off like a bullet) - my Vespa stalls. If, however, I give it full gas - then Vespa rides off with no problem. After riding it for around 5 minutes, giving it only a little bit of gas doesn't seem to be a problem. Is that a normal behavior for that kind of engine, or I should contact my dealer for a replacement?

Comment: Conversely: it's almost a party trick to tip up your electric bike by opening the throttle like you would with an IC bike. You need to give the Vespa enough gas. Anyway, does it have an automatic or manual choke? Either way, you can't really expect an IC bike to perform well until it is warmed up. I suggest it's just a matter of readjusting your riding from electric to gas.

Comment: It should be automatic choke, since the engine uses fuel injection instead of carburetor.

Answer (score 0):

Check the owner's manual. Does the manual say, "After a cold start, avoid giving it just a little gas or it will stall; after 5 minutes you can drive it any way you wish."

Not likely!

It's a brand new moped. You are entitled to a vehicle that does not stall if driven according to the terms of the owner's manual. You should return to the dealer and insist on proper operation.

Don't expect a replacement moped. A technician will check it and see if something is out of adjustment. They might want you to leave it overnight so they can start it cold and duplicate the problem.

After adjustment or repair, it should not stall. And there should be no cost to you.